# Replace column in header of a large .txt file - unix

Tags: unix, awk, sed, header, large-files

i need to replace the date in header of a large file. So i have multiple column in header, using |(pipe) as separator, like this:
A|B05|1|xxc|2018/06/29|AC23|SoOn

So i need the same header but with the date(5th column) updated : A|B05|1|xxc|2018/08/29|AC23

Any solutions for me? I tried with awk and sed but both of them carried me errors greater than me. I'm new on this and i really want to understand the solution. So could you please help me?

Comment: Show your work and the error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use below command which replaces 5th column from every line with content of newdate variable:**

```
awk -v newdate="2018/08/29" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{ $5 = newdate }1' infile > outfile
```

**Explanation**

```
awk -v newdate="2018/08/29" '    # call awk, and set variable newdate 
    BEGIN{
           FS=OFS="|"            # set input and output field separator
    }
    { 
           $5 = newdate          # assign fifth field with a content of variable newdate
    }1                           # 1 at the end does default operation 
                                 # print current line/row/record, that is print $0
  ' infile > outfile
```

**If you want to skip first line incase if you have header then use `FNR>1`**

```
awk -v newdate="2018/08/29" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}FNR>1{ $5 = newdate }1' infile > outfile
```

**If you want to replace 5th column in 1st row only then use `FNR==1`**

```
awk -v newdate="2018/08/29" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}FNR==1{ $5 = newdate }1' infile > outfile
```

> If you still have problem, frame your question with sample input and
>   expected output, so that it will be easy to interpret your problem.

Comment: This is awesomee. The right solution for me is the last one and works properly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Short ***sed*** solution:

```
sed -Ei '1s~\|[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}\|~|2018/08/29|~' file
```

- `-i` - modify the file in-place
- `1s` - substitute only in the 1st(header) line
- `[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}` - date pattern

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. When i use your solution i receive an error message <<sed: 1: "header.txt": extra characters at the end of h command>>

Comment: @Light, use this `sed -E -i.bak '1s~\|[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}\|~|2018/08/29|~' file`